# How does this battery charger circuit work?

Tags: charger

I am having a hard time figuring out how this circuit works. This is a portion of a circuit which uses AC mains (220 V) to charge a 9 V rechargeable battery.

I have added the schematic and the representation of the PCB wiring.

Can someone kindly help translate this into a schematic or explain how this circuit works?

**SOLVED** - based on @transitor's guidance. The deciphered schematic is as below.

[image: PCB schematic]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI1pmT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: We're too lazy to figure the circuit out for you. If you want an answer, draw a **proper** schematic.

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: The other end of the R2 resistor is not connected to ground. It is connected to its own island. You can translate it into a schematic yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the schematic button @transistor. I am new here and feeling my way around.

Comment: Good. Now have a look at the PCB and your schematic. There are two diodes, D3 and D1, connected to the right side of the capacitor on the PCB but only one in your schematic (and you've called it D2). There are probably other errors. Check it out carefully. Double-click the components on your schematic and edit the component numbers to match the PCB.

Comment: @transistor - Thank you! I have reworked the schematic and went on simplifying it, till a clear picture emerged. The big learning was to name the PCB and schematic components with the same name and secondly check the neighbors of each component. Thanks for lighting the path for me.

Comment: That's called "reverse engineering". I did a lot of it in my youth when there were hardly any programmable devices and you could figure out how everything worked by looking up the pinouts and datasheets. It's a bit harder now but a useful skill for repairs.

Comment: @Sandeep Deb: There is a "slight" difference (factor \$10^9\$) if R1 is 1MOhm (PCB) or 1mOhm (circuit diagram). In the latter case you battery may be charged very very fast :-)

Comment: This charger could electrocute you if you touch the battery while charging . DO NOT connect anything to the battery while you are charging .Under some circumstances this circuit is NOT SAFE

Comment: @Curd - :) Indeed.. I have changed the schematic. From m to M.

Comment: I am still puzzled as to how the LED would work. Should it not blow out? The 150K resistor is a 0.5 W or less (tiny thing). Any insights?

Comment: @SandeepDeb From \$P = V^2/R\$, we get \$\frac{(120V * \sqrt{2} - 2.0V)^2}{150k\Omega} \simeq 0.19W \$, so even a quarter watt resistor should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very poorly drawn schematic.  It is obfuscating the fact that this is basically a full wave bridge with series capacitor to limit current.  For good measure, it throws in a LED that is likely reverse biased well beyond its spec for part of every AC cycle.

Forget about this mess and move on.